# Highcharts x axis formatting options

Tags: json, highcharts

I am a beginner for highcharts. I was trying something and got stuck. My x axis has values  repeated multiple times. Tooltip values should contain date and time as shown. but the thing i want to change is the x axis values. same value must be shown only once and not repeated everywhere where there is data.

X axis format must be DD-MMM and tooltip should be DD-MM-YY HH am/pm .
is this possible?

Here is my trial code

http://jsfiddle.net/j6oqcgp2/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'spline'
},
title: {
    text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
},
xAxis: {

    categories:['01-Feb-17 12 AM','01-Feb-17 01 AM','01-Feb-17 02 AM','02-Feb-17 04 AM','02-Feb-17 05 AM','02-Feb-17 06 AM','02-Feb-17 07 AM'],
    labels: {                
                    formatter: function () {
                             y=(this.value).substring(1,6);

                        return  y;
                    }


}
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Snow depth (m)'
    },
    min: 0
},
tooltip: {

    formatter: function () {

            y=(this.x).substring(0,15);
            return y;
        },
        shared:false


},

plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Winter 2012-2013',
    // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
    // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
    // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
    data: [5,10,19,10,4,6,8]


}]
```

});

[and this is how i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQHre.png)

Comment: For starters, since you're plotting timeseries data, I would use a `datetime` axis type. This will make working with the date information much more intuitive, and remove the need for silly things getting a substring of a category value. Then, it's still a matter of controlling `tickInterval` as noted in Mike's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If your x-axis categories are going to be a predictable set of values (for example, four readings on each day), then you simply can add the `tickInterval` attribute to show a new axis label on when the day changes (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval).

So, if you had four readings per day, you would add `tickInterval: 4` to your x-axis options. This would show an axis label at every fourth reading, or, in this example, once per day.

If, however, your x-axis categories are not predictable (for example, any number of readings per day), you may want to look at this Highcharts demo, which shows a chart with irregular time periods: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time. In this demo, you'll see regular, non-repeating axis labels for whatever unit you're measuring (hours, days, etc.) and the data being plotted as frequently as it's recorded in the data.

I hope these examples and resources are helpful for you.

Comment: I am actually retrieving data from json array for highcharts, which gives an hourly data, the data in a day can be N numbers. On X axis i should get the **Plotinterval**  for a day, where as the data has to be plotted for every hour if there is data.
Please see attached screen shot image above. This is how i want the data to be displayed.
Those are the actual values i am trying to represent on highcharts.